# How to set bundler version in heroku?

Tags: heroku, bundler

I need to specific the ruby version in my gemfile but my app in heroku is using the old bundler version 1.0.7.

If I include `gem 'bundler', '1.3.2'` in my gemfile it failed when I push to heroku.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (= 1.3.2)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.0.7)

Your version of Bundler is older than the one requested by the Gemfile.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
```

I also try running `heroku run "gem install bundler"` and it return permission error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
 directory.
```

How can i set the Bundler version to 1.3.2 in heroku so that I can specific ruby version?

Comment: Are you on the Cedar stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku manages bundler as part of stack. I'm guessing you are on the Bamboo stack as that uses 1.0.7 whereas Cedar is using 1.3.x version.

If you're on Bamboo then you don't have any options I'm afraid, aside from upgrading to Cedar where you will get all the latest goodness.

Comment: Thanks John Beynon. Yes I am on Bamboo stack. How can I migrate to Cedar stack?

Comment: Heroku have a whole article on it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration

Comment: Thanks. I have migrated to Cedar stack and now my bundler 1.3.2.